# Set Vuex IsMobile value at application load

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I want to set the value of isMobile variable to true or false (based on which device the user is using) in vuex with some function that runs when the application is loaded and not from inside any components.

the `isMobile()` function would be something like this:

```js
isMobile() {
  if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
},
```

And the state variable would be something like this:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import * as actions from './actions.js';
import * as mutations from './mutations.js';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const state = {
  isMobile: true 
};

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state,
  actions,
  mutations
});
```

I know that I must use Actions and Mutations but the point is how can I run them from outside every components just once when the application is loaded?

Comment: Why not just initialise the `isMobile` state property from your `isMobile()` function? Eg `const state = { isMobile: isMobile() }`

Comment: @Phil thanks, it seems to work this way :)